# Can't get CircleCI to post to Slack upon test failure

Tags: cypress

I'm getting no parsing errors and i believe my config.yml is correct, I just can't seem to get it to post to slack, i have all the backgrounc config correct such as the environment variables and the context part is what we call to our organization settings, it's just not posting upon failure, is there something i'm doing wrong?

```
version: 2.1
orbs:
  cypress: cypress-io/cypress@1
  slack: circleci/slack@4.5.0
workflows:
  version: 2
  test:
    jobs:
      - cypress/run

jobs:
  steps:
    executors:
    with-chrome:
    docker:
      - image: 'cypress/browsers:node14.16.0-chrome90-ff88'
    description: Runs cypress tests
    steps:
      - checkout
      - run:
          name: Run all cypress tests
          command: npx cypress run
          context: slack-context
      - slack/notify:
          event: fail
          template: basic_fail_1
```

Answer (score 0):

It appears you're using the CircleCI Cypress orb, and more specifically the `cypress/run` job defined in that orb. So I'm not sure what the part

```
jobs:
  steps:
    executors:
    with-chrome:
    docker:
      - image: 'cypress/browsers:node14.16.0-chrome90-ff88'
    description: Runs cypress tests
    steps:
      - checkout
      - run:
          name: Run all cypress tests
          command: npx cypress run
          context: slack-context
      - slack/notify:
          event: fail
          template: basic_fail_1
```

is for.

The way your config looks, that part will never be executed. Your build will be simply the [`cypress/run` job](https://circleci.com/developer/orbs/orb/cypress-io/cypress?version=1.29.0#jobs-run) running with all the default parameters' values.

Further more, contexts need to be referenced within the `workflows` section (https://circleci.com/docs/2.0/contexts/).

I would suggest the below configuration:

```
version: 2.1

orbs:
  cypress: cypress-io/cypress@1.29.0
  slack: circleci/slack@4.10.1

executors:
  with-chrome:
    docker:
      - image: 'cypress/browsers:node14.16.0-chrome90-ff88'
workflows:
  version: 2
  test:
    jobs:
      - cypress/run:
          executor: with-chrome
          browser: chrome
          context: slack-context
          post-steps:
            - slack/notify:
                event: fail
                template: basic_fail_1
```